# Yii2 одна страница открывается по двум адресам?

Tags: php, yii2

Версия Advanced. Во frontend/config/main прописываю:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        'about' => 'site/about',
        'contact' => 'site/contact',
        'login' => 'site/login',
    ],
],
```

Страница about работает по адресам:

```
domain.com/about
domain.com/site/about
```

Это не корректно, одна страница должна открываться по одному адресу. Как это поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/308948/). В особенности на часть про свойство `enableStrictParsing`. Это может Вам помочь.